# Is it possible to "og:read" an "og:article" using Facebook's OpenGraph?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

It appears that both "read" and "article" are built in actions / objects on Facebook's open graph. Unfortunately, it's not clear how to use the two together.

I tried to create a "my-namespace:read" action on the object "og:article", but I can't find the object "og:article." (even though https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ lists article as a type).

This is a problem for me because I'm trying to register a user action on existing websites that already uses the open graph protocol. [This page](http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/205806-pepper-spray-cop-casually-pepper-spray-everything-cop), for example, has the type "og:article." If I try to define my own "read" and my own "article", it won't work as FB will tell me "< said webpage > is of type 'og:article' and not of type 'my-namespace:article.'

Answer (score 0):

Under Connected Objects, try choosing the "article" that appears in the typeahead when you don't have your own article defined. That is og:article.

You can also change the og type and it won't impact your existing likes.